# Shooting with a camera and then pausing while recording

Tags: camcorder

We're shooting basketball videos, and I would like to be able to Pause/Rewind while continuing to record, so I can show the coaches of the team the video, while the players are still playing.

Is there something in Adobe Premiere that will allow you to do this, or will I need to buy a PVR or something?

We currently are looking to buying a new camcorder, and getting the entire setup created. Basically we want to be able to record all of our games straight to a computer via a capture card or direct Firewire out of the camera, and then be able to Pause/Rewind/Scrub through the video, but when we are pausing and scrubbing, we still need to be able to catch back up to "Real Time", basically like a DVR in a TV.

Comment: Most PVR's have that ability nowadays.

Comment: So a PVR would have the ability to Play/Pause while continuing to record? Anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: I don't see how this question is not on-topic for Super User. Reopened accordingly. David, if your question doesn't get much attention, we can migrate it to [avp.SE] if you want. Just let us know by flagging it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like thee is a cheap or easy way to do what you want to do.
I use premiere a lot and.  There are mutlicam features for Premiere that allow you to sync to tracks and edit them easily, not to do live recording and playback at the same time.
If you stop and start the recording on lulls in the game where nothing is happening you will generate files that can be played back while the computer is recording the next file.

Also
Most computers video cards have an HDMI out, and can output to two monitors.
wire one output through a PVR and use that to rewind etc.  I don't have any experience with a pvr but that might work.

Comment: Yea - I think I may of found my answer in a program called EyeTV 3, but I'm open for other options! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [MythTV](http://www.mythtv.org/), a very good open source DVR.

A more complete list of free DVR applications can be found on Wikipedia's [Digital video recorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_video_recorder#Linux) page.